# Using Sleep command in Crontab CentOS

Tags: php, linux, centos, cron

I am trying to execute a php script in conjunction with the Sleep command from Crontab. Here is the relevant code:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash 
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin 
MAILTO=root HOME=/  
# run-parts 

* * * * * sleep 5 && root /usr/bin/php /path/to/the/php/file.php
```

But it won't execute at all. Any hints?

Comment: @inquisitor sorry that's a type in my post, it is lowercase but still nothing

Comment: Execute the job and then `cat /var/log/syslog` to see why its failing.

Comment: @fedorqui every second? * * * * * is a representation for 1 minute. (I'm quite sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `root` from `sleep 5 && root /usr..`

If you want to run it as root, the correct format is:

`* * * * * root sleep 5 && /usr/bin/php /path/to/the/php/file.php`